# Can not format dual mSATA enclosured mSATA SSD

Tags: hard-drive, raid, formatting, msata

I got a dual mSATA enclosure to 2½ SATA convertor from Startech. My hard drives are 2 SanDisk 64GB mSATA SSD's. I am trying to create a RAID0 array to load my windows 10 on it as my main drive for the OS.

It has jumper setting and I've set them to RAID 0 as it was explained how on 
[its website](http://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/sets/25SAT22MSAT_Manual/25SAT22MSAT.pdf).

It also has a second jumper for enabling changes on RAID config. That is set to unlock.

When I'm trying to format the drive it comes up with error formatting drive was not successful.

I tried removing the volume and adding partition but no luck. It adds the partition but error message comes up saying cant finish formatting.

I used third party applications like paragon 14(licenced) and there it comes with error cant do it if I want to ignore the error and do it anyway. 
never done it as I don't want to damage the SSD. 
I have no data on it its a new drive, I just need to load OS windows 10 on it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I don't want to damage the SSD." - You are worried about something that cannot be done.  You cannot damage hardware through software.

Answer (score 2):

Did you notice the section at the bottom of page 6 that asks you to set the RAID configuration to JBOD, prior to making any changes?

This is before the 'Set RAID Configuration' section, but it is clearly intended to be part of that section - not before it.

> Your RAID configuration **must be set to JBOD before the device can be
>   reconfigured** to RAID 0, RAID 1, or BIG. If you have set a different
>   RAID configuration and now wish to reconfigure your RAID, please set
>   the device back to JBOD before changing the configuration again.

Comment: I have put it back to JBOD and connected it to computer (3 deferent computers ) and it is known as 64 gb , only one of the drives , that's fine , that's how it should be ,

Comment: then I changed the raid configuration to raid 0 pin 12 and 45 and it is configured as raid zero as it is showing on disk management , but I can not give it a drive letter when adding a volume to it

Comment: comes up with an error saying formatting cant be completed

Comment: You have it currently Unlocked (SET-GND) correct?

Comment: ok I have looked into it a bit more and I found out that the card is actualy faulty , it only recognizes one of the drives ,

Comment: i asked for a replacement , hopefully i wont have a problem with the other one